# Mascara de entrada de medidas em metro

Tags: java, android, edittext

Estou desenvolvendo um App de cálculo de BTUs de ar condicionado, que simplesmente recebe unidades de medidas e recomenda uma capacidade de ar condicionado adequada para o ambiente.
O problema é que quero que o usuário consiga separa os metros do centímetro sem necessidade dele inserir manualmente o "." para isso, que fosse feito automático de acordo com que for digitando como é feita com a mascara monetária.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editLargura;
    private EditText editComprimento;
    private TextView textResultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editLargura = findViewById(R.id.editLargura);
        editComprimento = findViewById(R.id.editComprimento);
        textResultado = findViewById(R.id.textResultado);

    }

    public  void realizarCalculo (View view){

        String largura = findViewById(R.id.editLargura).toString();
        String comprimento = findViewById(R.id.editComprimento).toString();

        Boolean camposValidados = this.validarCampos (largura, comprimento);
        if (camposValidados){

            this.calcularMelhorPotencia(largura, comprimento);

        }else{
            textResultado.setText("Preencha os campos primeiro" +
                    " e caso não tenha pessoas ou eletrônicos digite 0 nesses campos");
        }

    }

    public void calcularMelhorPotencia(String mLargura, String mComprimento){
        Double medidasLargura = Double.parseDouble(mLargura);
        Double medidasComprimento = Double.parseDouble(mComprimento);

        Double resultado = medidasLargura * medidasComprimento;

        if( resultado >= 3000 && resultado  <= 7000 ){
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 7.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 7001 && resultado <= 9000 ) {
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 9.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 9001 && resultado <= 12000 ){
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 12.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 12001 && resultado <= 18000 ){
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 18.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 18001 && resultado <= 22000 ){
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 22.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 22001 && resultado <= 30000 ){
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 30.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 30001 && resultado <= 36000 ){
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 36.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 36001 && resultado <= 48000 ){
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 48.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 48001 && resultado <= 60000 ){
            textResultado.setText("Para esse ambiente terá que instalar um ar condicionado de 60.000 BTU´s");
        }else if( resultado >= 60001 ){
            textResultado.setText("Será necessário entrar em contato com a Okay Ar Condicionado para criação de um projeto de climatização");
        }
    }
    public Boolean validarCampos(String mLargura, String mComprimento){
        Boolean camposValidados = true;
        if (mLargura==null || mComprimento.equals("")){
            camposValidados = false;
        }else if (mLargura==null || mComprimento.equals("")){
            camposValidados = false;
        }

        return camposValidados;
    }

}
```

E esse é o layout xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPessoas"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ex: 2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="digite a largura"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editLargura"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ex: 3.25"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="digite o comprimento"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Saiba qual a potência de ar condicionado compra"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editComprimento"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ex: 4.12"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="205dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="digite quantas pessoas"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editLargura" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="digite quantos eletrônicos"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editComprimento" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEletronicos"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ex: 3"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:onClick="realizarCalculo"
        android:text="verificar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editEletronicos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textResultado"
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Clique no botão após preencher os campos"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/system_notification_accent_color"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia amigo.... há duas maneiras de se fazer isso: 1º Através de código ou então da 2º maneira que é bem mais simples e que vou mostrar pra você logo abaixo:

** 1º Implementação **

- Adicione a seguinte linha ao seu build.gradle

`implementation 'com.github.santalu:mask-edittext:1.0.2`

** 2º Adicionando ao xml **

- Substitua o EditText que vai receber a entrada por `<com.santalu.maskedittext.MaskEditText` ou seja, veja o exemplo abaixo:

  < com.santalu.maskedittext.MaskEditText 
      android:id="@+id/editPessoas"
      android:layout_width="138dp"
      android:layout_height="43dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:ems="10"
      android:hint="ex: 2"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"       app:met_mask="#.## m" />

Onde `app:met_mask="#.## m"` é a máscara que você quer aplicar. Para cada `#` equivale a um dígito pelo usuário.

** 3º Recupere o valor digitado **

- Você pode recuperar o valor digitado de 2 formas diferentes:

> O valor com a máscara:

`String aString      =   maskText.getRawText().trim();`

- Ex de saída.: 1.35 m

> O valor sem a máscara:

`String aString      =   maskText.getText().toString().trim();`

- Ex de saída.: 135

Comment: boa tarde amigo! Obrigado pela extrema ajuda, isso já trabalha como eu queria e posso dar seguimento no meu projeto, apenas queria saber se há algum método que permita movimentar o ponto para frente de acordo com que for digitando mais números ou se limitam ao modelo que é declarado no xml como  app:met_mask="#.##" e caso digitasse mais números mudasse para  app:met_mask="##.##" e ponto permanecesse fixo antes dos dois últimos dígitos.

Comment: voce quer fazer como nos aplicativos de bancos é isso?